# creating file paths from 2d lists kdb q

Tags: kdb

Say I have a list of files

```
`(`fileA`fileB`fileC;`fileX`fileY)
```

And a list of paths

```
`:a/b`:c/d
```

how can I concatenate these so produce

```
`:a/b/fileA`:a/b/fileB`:a/b/fileC`:c/d/fileX`:c/d/fileX
```

I would usually use

```
` sv'paths,'filelist
```

But in this case since `filelist is 2d and the lengths do not match it produces

```
`:a/b/fileA/fileB/fileC`:c/d/fileX/fileY
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `each-both` and `each-right` :

```
q)raze{` sv/:(x,/:y)}'[(`:a/b`:c/d ) ;(`fileA`fileB`fileC;`fileX`fileY)]
`:a/b/fileA`:a/b/fileB`:a/b/fileC`:c/d/fileX`:c/d/fileY
```

each-right is appending the files to the dir :

```
q){` sv/:(x,/:y)}[`:a/b;`fileA`fileB`fileC]
`:a/b/fileA`:a/b/fileB`:a/b/fileC
```

Comment: Can make it a bit shorter(and avoid lambda) by doing:
  q) ` sv/:raze a,/:'b  /

where
a = list of dirs
b = list of files,

Answer (score 2):

Could also use the built-in .Q.dd

```
q).Q.dd''[`:a/b`:c/d;(`fileA`fileB`fileC;`fileX`fileY)]
`:a/b/fileA`:a/b/fileB`:a/b/fileC
`:c/d/fileX`:c/d/fileY
```